# JBoss 7, how to add library module to eclipse project build path

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, module, dependencies, jboss7.x

I wanted to move from jboss AS 6 to 7 with hibernate 4 support and now all libraries are in subfolders with module.xml files.

And I have no idea how to add those to my eclipse project build path.

Where do I define my module dependencies?

Comment: Are you using a normal Java project, or WTP or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to do Build Path > Add External Archives and select the jars you want.

Slightly better might be to define a JBOSS_HOME classpath variable, and add the jars as variable entries. That would make things easier if you ever move your JBoss installation.

If you wanted more automation, it would be possible to write a script, for whatever build tool you use, that parses your application's manifest to find which modules it depends on, and add those to your classpath automatically. If you're good at scripting, that should be quite easy.

Comment: Thanks, i hoped there was already a solution for it. I am still testing around with jboss or glassfish.

Comment: It's possible there is already a solution that i don't know about. I'm by no means an expert. Have you tried the AS7 forum? I've asked a few questions there, and never got a good answer, but it might be worth a go.